# How to show modularity of an elliptic curve?

Tags: nt.number-theory

In the days before [W, TW, BCDT], how did people show that specific elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ were modular? For instance, I was reading through a paper of Buhler, Gross and Zagier from 1985 on the curve 5077a, and they say that modularity can be checked by a finite computation in the 422-dimensional space of cuspforms of weight 2 and level 5077 (and remark at the end that Serre and Mestre have checked it). A google search brought up the name "Faltings-Serre method": was this the technique of choice? Also, are there any good references for it?

Comment: Could you please explain who do you mean by W, TW and BCDT? I just recoqnize Brian Conrad and Wiles ...

Comment: I'm referring to the papers by Wiles, Taylor-Wiles, and Breuil-Conrad-Diamond-Taylor.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They explicitly computed quotients of $X_0(N)$ and identified them with elliptic curves.
Suppose you can compute the space $S_2(\Gamma_0(N),\mathbf{C})$ of modular forms. An (isogeny class of) elliptic curves of conductor $N$ corresponds (by modularity) to a normalized new Hecke eigenform with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}$. Given such an $f$, one can compute the periods of $f$, which allows one to write down a Weierstrass equation for $f$. If one can do this in such a way to guarantee that the coefficients of the Weierstrass equation are *integers*, this allows one to computationally determine exactly the modular elliptic curves of conductor $N$. All this is very well explained in Cremona's book, which is available free online:

http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/book/amec.html

The particular method referred to in the paper of [BGZ] was presumably the "method of graphs", see for example here:

http://modular.math.washington.edu/msri06/refs/mestre-method-of-graphs/mestre-en.pdf

The Faltings-Serre method is slightly different; it allows you to determine, given two Galois representations $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ from
$G_{K}$ to (say) $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ such that:

1. $\overline{\rho}_1 \simeq \overline{\rho}_2$,
2. $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ are both unramified outside some finite (given) set of places $S$ of $K$.

whether $\rho_1 \simeq \rho_2$. You could use it to prove that an elliptic curve $E/\mathbf{Q}$ is modular by comparing the Galois representation attached to the $p$-adic Tate module of $E$ and the Galois representation attached to the conjecturally corresponding eigenform of level $N$ (EDIT: this works because the Galois representation determines the isogeny class of $E$ by Faltings' proof of the Tate conjecture for abelian varieties). However, this wouldn't be so efficient. However, there *are* other situations (for example, elliptic curves over other number fields) where the corresponding automophic form is not enough to compute the periods. In this case, the Faltings-Serre method can be used to prove modularity. Taylor uses this to prove that a certain elliptic curve over $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$ is modular.

Comment: For those who prefer to read Mestre in French, 
William Stein's site has the original too:
$$ $$
http://boxen.math.washington.edu/msri06/refs/mestre-method-of-graphs/mestre-fr.pdf
$$ $$ 


Comment: There is also a paper of Dieulefait, Guerberoff and Pacetti (see http://arxiv.org/abs/0804.2302) where they use the Faltings-Serre method to prove modularity of some elliptic curves over imaginary quadratic fields.

Answer (score 21):

The general "standard approach" was to use the suite of algorithms described in [Cremona's book](http://www.warwick.ac.uk/~masgaj/book/fulltext/) (which is now freely available).  The basic idea is to use modular symbols to write down a basis for the homology of the modular curve $X_0(N)$, then use the action of Hecke operators to compute all of the rational cuspidal newforms of level $N$.  To each newform there is a corresponding optimal elliptic curve quotient of $X_0(N)$, whose equation can be analytically computed exactly (this uses Edixhoven's remark that the Manin constant is an integer); once that optimal curve has been computed there are standard formulas to list all curves isogenous to it.   Thus to prove that a given elliptic curve $E$ is modular, first compute its conductor $N$ (using Tate's algorithm), then enumerate *all* the modular elliptic curves of conductor $N$ (via Cremona's algorithm), and finally note that $E$ is in this list.

If you're interested in efficiency there are shortcuts, e.g., instead of finding all rational newforms, just find the one that looks like it comes from your curve $E$.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, William and Wanax! William: it seems I can only accept one answer, so accepting Wanax's because of its multiple references. Hope you don't mind!

Comment: Regarding complexity, I just mentioned this post to Cremona and he remarks: "...and doing level 5077 takes under 1 second now"

Comment: @Abhinav: Amusingly, Wanax's one extra reference is to a paper hosted on my website that I got a student to translate into English.  :-)   (I don't care about the points stuff.)

Answer (score 5):

The answer is outlined in Don Zagier's 1985 paper [*Modular points, modular curves, modular surfaces and modular forms*](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BFb0084592/fulltext.pdf).